# A way to define / implement failover ldap servers in java code

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have the following code for Ldap user authentication:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;


public class LdapUtil {
    public static final String PROVIDER_URL= "ldap://ourLdapServer";
    public static final String SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION="simple";
    public static final String SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_POSTFIX="@org.local";
    private String ldapAttributes[] = null;

    public boolean isCorrectUser(String user, String pass){
        boolean result = false;
        if (user == null || pass == null || "".equals(user) || "".equals(pass)) {
            return result;
        }
    try {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_POSTFIX);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
            LdapContext ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            ldapAttributes = getUserBasicAttributes(user,ctxGC);
            ctxGC.close();
            result = true;
            //System.out.println("LDAP authentication for " + username + " succeeded!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Not authenticated
            result = false;  
           //System.out.println("LDAP authentication for " + username + " failed!");

        }
     return result;
    }

}
```

There is one main drawback - it works only for **one** Ldap server.

Now I would like to define alternative Ldap servers for fail-over purposes   (e.g. when the main ldap is down or is not accessible - the program should try  to query the secondary ldap, if that is not available next one etc.).

How would I achieve that?

And how would I minimise authentication time if the primary server would stay offline for a long time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an alternative to making the code more complex consider a disaster recovery plan which simply changes the DNS entry of `ldap://ourLdapServer` to the back up server.

Comment: @AndrewS Unfortunately this is out of my reach. Ldap, dns etc are configured by the technical division and thus the only thing that I CAN control is my own code... thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add multiple LDAP PROVIDER_URLs:

```
// Specify list of [space-separated URL][1]s
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
    "ldap://ourLdapServer " +
    "ldap://ourLdapServer2 " + 
    "ldap://ourLdapServer3 " +
    "ldap://ourLdapServer4");
```

Comment: You are absolutely right - just figured it out yesterday! Was not expecting this to be so easy ;-) I'll leave in comments a link for a future reference. [LDAP & LDAPS URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html). Thanks for reply.